# Is there an easy way of generating a case class that contains another case class object?

Tags: scala

Let's say we have a with some parameters:

```
case class Person
```

Now, I want to create a case class that contains a single element:

```
person: Person
```

(since things like Ember require that)

I also want to generate the case class

```
persons: Seq[Person]
```

Is there any way I can generate both of these?

Something that would have the signature along the lines of

```
generateListType[T](T, Seq[T])
```

where I could do

```
generateListType(Person, List(Person("test"), Person("test2"))
```

which then would create the JSON

```
{
    "persons": [{"name": "person 1"}, {"name", "person 2"}]
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to generate json from case classes? If so, take a look at https://github.com/spray/spray-json

Comment: FYI: Ember (>=2.0) requires http://jsonapi.org/ by default, your example is not valid JSON API

Comment: @Wellingr for case classes is fine, but I want an ember-friendly format to be generated also. And I'm looking for a clean solution for precisely that.